# Intrusion system suggestion specifically for Centos 6.4

Tags: centos

We are trying to evaluate a good possible intrusion detection package specifically for centos 6.4. So far Ossec looks promising. Any other based on others experience.

Answer (score 2):

I had once made a study on HIDS software.
However, this most was in the purpose of providing integrity control for PCI-DSS certification.

While **OSSEC** provides very good log parsing solutions, **Samhain** was the best in terms of possibilities of integrity control.
Specifically, it proposes modes for checking log files which are being appended, GPG signing of configuration and database files, a centralized architecture or stand-alone, and many more.
Plus it still receives regular updates/fixes, and proposes commercial support if needed.

Another very good all-around and complete HIDS is **snort**, of course.

For the CentOS 6.4 part, Samhain always have to be compiled because most options are set at compile time.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: as you know Centos is a package distribution and compiling is always discourage due to  stability issues.

Comment: How does compiling a software yourself would cause stability issues ??

Answer (score 1):

Nexpose is fairly popular I believe.  It is more of a vulnerability detection system from what I gathered.  We used it at my last company on CentOS Linux 6.3 and it was able to pick up some information about vulnerabilities in our DNS configuration, among other things with minimal setup required.  We only used it on a trial basis, but were impressed with what we saw.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: We used Nexpose at my last company on a trial basis with very good results.  It also seems to be quite popular based on what I have heard online from others.  That is my experience, as requested by the original question.

Comment: While that is true, it would be helpful if you included some points about Nexpose's advantages, capabilities etc., and a link to the relevant website. The site is a wiki and answers should be self-contained.

Comment: @all any good thing about Ossec from any of your experiences?